# Почему не отправляет данные в базу данных?

Tags: php, mysql

Создал форму для отправки названия и автора композиции в базу данных(ее создал). Но почему то не отправляет, в чем ошибка?

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['music_name']) and isset($_POST['author_name'])) {
    $music_name = trim($_POST['music_name']);
    $author_name = trim($_POST['author_name']);
}

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'my_first_bd');

if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Соединение не установлено %s\n", mysqli_connect_errno());
    exit();
}

$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');

$query = "INSERT INTO music VALUES(1, $music_name, $author_name)";
$mysqli->query($query);

?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" method="post">
    <center><input type="text" name="music_name" placeholder="Введите имя">
        <input type="submit" value="отправить"></center>
</form>
<br>    
<form action = "#" method = "post">
    <center><input type="text" name="author_name" placeholder="Введите автора">
        <input type="submit" value="отправить"></center>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: потому что строковые значения обрамляются в одинарные кавычки в mysql

Comment: А вот если бы вы включили показ ошибок - вы бы увидели это в сообщении об ошибке

Comment: Ну и вдогонку - а если `isset($_POST['music_name'])` равен `false`, то какое значение у `$music_name`?

Comment: Заменил все двойные на одинарные, все равно не отправляет. К тому же пишет ошибку Unable to resolve table 'music'

Comment: потому что название таблицы и колонок пишутся в обратных кавычках а не одинарных

Comment: Исправил ошибки, но теперь пишет Undefined array key "author_name". Я думаю, что это из за неправильного написания двух форм, это так?

Comment: да, это так....